# Probability distributions of offspring.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose that a certain animal gives birth to a number of offspring $N$. Each child survives with probability $p$ the first year, independently of the other children. Let $Z_{1}$ denote the number of children alive after 1 year. When $N$ is fixed, $Z_{1}$ is binomially distributed, but it is more realistic to take $N$ random.

a) Suppose that $N$ is uniformly distributed on $\{0, 1, 2,\ldots, 10\}$. What is the expected number of offspring that survives after one year?

b) Suppose that $N$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$. What is the distribution of $Z$ (give a complete proof)?

c) We can generalise the above, by noting that every year the offspring has a survival probability $p$. Only birth is given to the initial $n$ children and no new offspring is introduced. Suppose $N = n$ fixed. What is the distribution of the number of animals alive after 10 years?

d) For $N = n$ fixed, we let $T(n)$ be equal to the first year that all of the offspring is dead. Give the distribution function of $T(n)$.

I managed to figure out b) such that the distribution of Z is $e^{-p\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}$. The other questions I cannot figure out. How are these questions supposed to be done?

Comment: Hint: a) $\mathbb E(Z_1)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{10} \mathbb E(Z_1|N=n)\cdot P(N=n)$

Comment: I don't understand the wording of part c really. Is it saying that $N=n$ children are introduced initially, and then no more reproduction happens, and then what is the distribution of the number of living offspring from that initial birth after 10 years? (Thus there is no "birth-death" dynamics, there is just a bunch of birth at the start and then death for the rest of time.)

Comment: @Ian I believe that is indeed what is being asked. Poor wording was a common trend throughout all of the exercises

Comment: If that's the interpretation, then the distribution is Bin($n,p^{10}$); each child needs to succeed at all 10 Bernoulli trials to survive

Comment: @callculus does this result in an actual numerical answer? I get
$Σ^{10}_{n=0} Σ_{z_{1}} \cdot P(Z_{1} = z_{1}, N=n)

Comment: The answer in part a depends on $p$, but in a way that you can easily evaluate, since $E(Z_1 \mid N=n)=np$ and $P(N=n)=1/11$.

Comment: @TKetelaar I agree to Ian.

Comment: Ah I believe I understand. Thank you